# How to make the placement of asterisks in a barplot easier?

Tags: r, bar-chart

I would like to place asterisks in my grouped barplot (R base) to indicate where the paired comparisons differ significantly. I know how to place these stars using the `points` command. However, from the posts that I read sofar it seems that one needs to find the right coordinates manually (e.g., group I: x=0.635, y=26, see the code below). This would take quite some time if one needs to find that out for all significant pairs.

So my question is: Is there an easier way to find the coordinates that correspond with the mid and just next to paired bars? I would prefer to do this in base plotting system at the moment but ggplot answers are also welcome. Thank you very much in advance!

**Data example**

```
set.seed(123)
dat<-matrix(runif(32, min = 0.5, max = 1), nrow=2, ncol=16)
colnames(dat)<-c(LETTERS[1:16])

par(mar=c(2,4,2,2)) 
mp<-barplot(dat, col=c("blue","red"), beside=TRUE, horiz=TRUE, xpd=FALSE, axes=FALSE, axisnames=TRUE, cex.names=0.8, las=2, xlim=c(0.5,1.0), main="Data Example") 

axis(1, at=seq(0.5,1.0, by=0.1))
axis(2, at=mp, labels=FALSE, tick=FALSE)

points(x=0.635, y=26, pch="*", cex=2) #sign position at I
```

[image]

Comment: I don't understand what your call to `axis(2, ...)` is for ? Also, how did you define `0.635`?

Comment: You are right, actually `axis(2, ...)` is redundant. 0.635 was defined by hand, trial and error. So that is basically my question: How to obtain that corresponding coordinate in an easier way, is it stored somewhere in the plot?

Comment: So, does my answer correspond to your needs? (I mean, did I understand your request right?). You can later define the "offset" (0.01 here) according to the interval between ticks for example to be sure it's not "range dependent".

Comment: Yes, this works, it is absolutely what I was looking for. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say you have a vector telling you which pairs are significant. For example:

```
sign <- rep(TRUE, 16) ; sign[c(5, 7, 13:14)] <- FALSE
```

you already know the y coordinates of the letters:

```
colMeans(mp)
```

so you can define the y coordinates of the asterisks:

```
ord_sign <- colMeans(mp)[sign]
```

For the x coordinates, you can place them for example 0.01 point to the right  from the max value:

```
abs_sign <- apply(dat, 2, max)[sign] + 0.01
```

Then you can draw all your asterisks at once:

```
points(x=abs_sign, y=ord_sign, pch="*", cex=2)
```

[image]